# SqlLite prepare_v2 error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm developing an app in c++ but get stuck on an error that occured whenever the program reach the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement

here is the code, Thanks a lot for your help !

```
int Database::save_lesson (Lesson *lesson) {
    int id ;
    std::ostringstream oss ;

    oss << "insert into lesson (name, teacher, place, begin, end)" ;
    oss << "values ( " ;
    oss << "'" << lesson->get_name()    << "', " ;
    oss << "'" << lesson->get_teacher() << "', " ;
    oss << "'" << lesson->get_slots() << "', "  ;
    oss << "'" << lesson->get_begin() << "', "  ;
    oss << "'" << lesson->get_end()   << "') ;" ;

    check (sqlite3_prepare_v2 (
            db,
            oss.str().c_str(),
            -1,
            &stmt,
            0)
    ) ;
    sqlite3_step(stmt) ;
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt) ;

    oss.clear();
    oss.str("");

    oss << "select max(id) from lesson ;" ;
// error occured here:
    check (sqlite3_prepare_v2 (
            db,
            oss.str().c_str(),
            -1,
            &stmt,
            0)
    ) ;
    sqlite3_step(stmt) ;
    id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0) ;
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt) ;

    return id ;
}
```

**EDIT**
The error message is: `bad parameter or other API misuse` (very helpful)

Comment: You forgot to include what kind of error you get, the exact error message you get and where it occurs. Letting us know if it's a compiler, linker, or runtime error is important.

Comment: Inspect, print, try in a SQLite console the string you are passing to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`

Comment: I added the errcode

Comment: @RichardCritten all good when printing and executing it raw in SQLite

Comment: Tell use *which* statement fails, and how you have initialized `db`.